# Replace a word using IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am using the IIS Rewrite module with my web.config, and would like to rewrite certain requests by replacing a word in the URL. 
Example: http://domain.com/windows to be http://domain.com/WINDOWSSoftware

I'm aware that a URL with query string  parameters can be rewritten using for example below rule

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to article.aspx">
      <match url="^article/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="article.aspx?id={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

Instead of /article?id=243&title=some-title we can have /article/234/some-title

I'm wondering if this can be achieved using URL Rewrite, or can it be done by developing a custom provider.

Comment: take a look https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396 RFC2396!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can definitely done with url rewrite module with bit of regex pattern matching.
http://domain.com/windows/sdfsdf

so if you just match {R:1} or {C:1} depending on how you setup

The final redirect can look like
{HTTP-HOST}/WindowsSoftware/{R:2}

Comment: <rule name="Replace_R1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(windows)(/.*)?" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http:/www.domain.com/WINDOWSSoftware/{R:2}" />
                </rule>

Comment: I havn't tested this but you can try something like that

Comment: Matching this ^(windows)(/.*)? will give you the {R:1} {R:2} options  what you are trying to achive